# Why can I not use vif when my model is made from a matrix

Tags: r, statistics

*I'm using an example based on cars for my inquiry here.*

I can use vif from the car package when the model is listed out.

```
vif(lm(mpg ~ wheels + tires + weight))
```

But let's say I combined wheels, tires, and weight to a matrix called "car_specs".
Now I can no longer use vif on the model.

```
vif(lm(mpg ~ car_specs))
```

I want to use vif in the second case for a function I wrote

```
Model_and_VIF <- function(...){
  #Getting list of names of the variables
  argnames = toupper(unlist(lapply(as.list(sys.call())[-1], deparse)))
  #making a list of vectors
  args = list(...)
  #Making a blank matrix
  data <- matrix(unlist(args[1]), ncol = 1,nrow = 4019)
  colnames(data) <- c(argnames[1])
  #Adding columns of other variabls
  for (i in 2:length(args)){
    data <- cbind(data, unlist(args[i]))
    colnames(data)[i] <- c(argnames[i])
  }
  dep <- data[,1]
  indep <- data[,2:ncol(data)]
  print(c(argnames[1], "vs.", argnames[2:length(argnames)]))
  print(summary(lm(dep ~ indep)))
  vif(lm(dep ~ indep))
}
```

Why will vif no longer work?

Here is some sample code

````
mdat <- matrix(c(1:150, 151:300), nrow = 100, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(mdat) <- c("boat", "coal", "grain")```
boat <- mdat[,1]
coal <- mdat[,2]
grain <- mdat[,3]
````

Comment: I also get the error ```Error in vif.default(lm(`dry index` ~ ContCor1)) : 
  model contains fewer than 2 terms```, but I still get the proper model with ```lm(`dry index` ~ ContCor1)``` ContCor1 is a matrix with more than 1 column

Comment: You can't use `lm` with a matrix, either...